# How to zoom charts in jupyterlab

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am plotting some charts with a fixed size.

I need to keep this size because they are later saved and embedded in a Latex document.

While working in jupyter they look too small.

I know I can change the size with matplotlib but this is not my point. I just want jupyter to zoom them (even if that means lower resolution in my notebook).

Is there a way I can increase the size when they are shown without touching matplotlib sizes?